# VueJs 2.0 Looping components and changing props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to handle looping components. Here is some example code.

This is kinda what I am trying to do. My main component has payments data which loops into child components.

```
<tr v-for="payment in payments"
is="component-payment-item"
:payment="payment
v-on:toggleReported="togglePaymentReported"">
 </tr>
```

My child component when it want's to mark a payment as reported, it just sends up an event. Which the parent component captures. So in the parent component I try this.

```
togglePaymentReported(payment) {
    payment.reported = ! payment.reported;
}
```

I know for sure this fires, however that change never goes back down to the child component. I don't know if this is the best way to handle this. The other way I thought is to actually find that payment in the array and change it that way but I figured it would be passed by reference and propagate down to the child component.

In vue 1.0 I would just change it on the child component it self. I know that is frowned upon and just not possible in vue2.0. What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the current payment to your `togglePaymentReported` method for it to receive it as an argument.

```js
pb = Vue.extend({
  template: '#paybutton-template',
  props: ['payment'],
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.$emit('toggle');
    }
  }
});

vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'payment-button': pb
  },
  data: {
    payments: []
  },
  methods: {
    handleToggle: function(payment) {
      payment.paid = !payment.paid;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    // Simulating setting from ajax
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.payments = [{
        id: 1,
        paid: false
      }, {
        id: 2,
        paid: false
      }];
    }, 800);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <payment-button v-for="payment in payments" :payment="payment" v-on:toggle="handleToggle(payment)"></payment-button>
</div>

<template id="paybutton-template">
  <div>
    {{payment.id}}: {{payment.paid}}
    <button @click="toggle">Pay</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It's still not updating the UI of my payment's item component. The only difference I really see in mine versus yours is that my v-for is on the same element as my component. I don't know why that would make a difference.  I can see it changing in vue dev tools.

Comment: Could it be because my payments come from a ajax request?

Comment: @mikelbring I've updated my example to put the v-for on the component tag. As long as you declared the payments in your `data`, setting their values from with an ajax request should not be a problem. Also simulated setting value via ajax.